# What is the term for the English idiom of "with high stakes"?

Tags: translation, idioms

In English there is the idiomatic expression "with high stakes." There is also the adjective high-stakes, which means involving serious risks if there is no success. Is there a similar idiom in Japanese?

> a "high-stakes" negotiation
>
> a conversation with "high stakes"

Comment: Good question. ALC lists いちかばちか in a couple of its entries as a TL for high-stakes, but that doesn’t seem that good, because いちかばちか is more about “going all in”/doing something *risky* as opposed to the thing on the line being very valuable/expensive/important...

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard  "to be with high stakes". What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: In similar situation we say like: [背水]{はいすい}の陣{じん}, （大きな）[賭]{か}け,（[大]{おお}）[勝負]{しょうぶ} and（[大]{おお}）[博打]{ばくち}.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky "To be with high stakes" means the same as the adjective "high-stakes," whose definition I gave in my question. For more context, please visit the website of the British Council - https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/intermediate-b1-listening/interview-about-listening-skills. The phrase "conversation with high stakes" is used there.

Comment: @TakumiSueda thank you very much!

Comment: @Enguroo: oh, so you meant to say "X with high stakes", not literal "to be with high stakes", which I've never seen.

Comment: Takumi Sueda's answers work for the definition given in the question, but not so much for the examples. I suggest expanding the definition to include situations that are not 背水の陣 because that is often not what "high-stakes" means in business and politics. For example. CEO wants to sell company and another company offers to buy. They have high-stakes negotiations as billions of dollars are at stake, but nobody is in any danger if a deal is not made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see more idiomatic phrase like [乾坤{けんこん}一擲{いってき}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B9%BE%E5%9D%A4%E4%B8%80%E6%93%B2/) の大勝負{おおしょうぶ}。

優勝をかけた敵地・福岡でのホークスとのプレーオフ。勝てば優勝という乾坤一擲の試合.

"*Playoff game for the Championship competing with Hawks at Fukuoka as away team. All or nothing game with high stakes to hit the jackpot.*"

or

一世{いっせい}一代{いちだい}の大勝負{おおしょうぶ}に出る is also used often when you are taking risk a lot.

「だから**一世一代の大勝負**に出て投資用にアパートを買っても、入居者がいなかったら毎月赤字を垂れ流すリスクがあった。」the sentence from [「利回り」で金を生む家・車・時計の選び方｜新R25](https://r25.jp/article/724072821109731641).

"*If you bought an apartment with high stakes for an investment and found no tenants, you had risk to face deficit every month.*"